# Uninstall git from centos 6.5 , and make install it in appointed location

Tags: git, centos6

I download git 2.8.1 tar.gz package from https://github.com/git/git/releases, and did that install it:

```
# tar -zxvf git-2.8.1.tar.gz
# cd git-2.8.1
# make
# make install
```

It worked successfully! But I don't know where it located, so I want uninstall git, and install it in appointed location. My OS version is CentOS 6.5 64bit, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `make install` command contains information about where `git` is being installed.  If you look in the `Makefile`, you can find that the default install location -- identified by the `prefix` variable -- is your home directory:

```
prefix = $(HOME)
```

The `make install` process will install files into subdiretories of `$(prefix)`, such as `$(HOME)/bin` for the executables, or `$(HOME)/share/man` for the man pages.

You can select a different install location by specifying a new value for `prefix` on the `make install` command line.  E.g:

```
make install prefix=/usr/local
```